# Converting from ISO-LATIN to UTF-8

Tags: encoding, asp-classic

I get a string by encoding ISO-LATIN in classic asp. I want to change this string to utf-8. How can I do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[C# Convert string from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 (Latin1) H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/c-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-latin1-h)

just the other way round

Comment: have you tried the correct marked answer? If yes please show your code