# SQL Server - how do I replace "weird" characters? How to encode a UTF-8 HTML response as ASCII?

Tags: c#, sql, character

I'm inserting some text into a SQL Server database using some C#.  I'm using System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() to attempt to replace characters that aren't compatible with the charset of my db (set to default collation = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS), but it is not helping me with some "weird" characters.

For example, this dash character:
―
is different from the standard dash character. (-)

HtmlEncode() doesn't replace the first dash with an entity (I think it is "&mdash;") and it ends up as a "?" in my database.

What is the best way to clean / sanitize a text field before inserting into SQL Server?

I would rather not change my database configuration / collation.

Comment: "―" is not an HTML metacharacter, so `HtmlEncode()` is not going to do anything to it. SQL and HTML metacharacters are completely different anyway; why are you putting HTML metacharacters in an SQL database?

Comment: *Use* placeholders, and N[VAR]CHAR columns for Unicode .. not sure of a standard way to replace with HTML [*character entities*](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref), though. (Would also have to encoded all other non-ASCII characters, even without official entity names ..)

Comment: Dour, I would rather not put HTML into the text fields, but I will if it gets rid of these question marks that I get for unrecognized characters.

Comment: @Dudeman3000 The fundamental issue with the `?` is that Latin != Unicode, and `―` is not in the CP. You're putting in HTML. The question is then just how to *encode* it - which could be done entirely with HTML *character entities*. (HtmlEncode doesn't do this because normally a UTF stream is served back and such is not required to avoid preventing HTML injection messes. This task is really "How to encode a UTF-8 HTML response as ASCII?") I suggest widening the column to N[VAR]CHAR and avoid the mess ..

Comment: You need to use `Encoding.Convert` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/). HTML has nothing to do with the issue or solution.

Comment: pst, yes, I think NVARCHAR fields instead of VARCHAR fields would help me out, but what I'm really looking for is a piece of code someone's written that is going to make getting rid of / replacing incompatible characters as painless as possible.  I'm hoping there is a piece of code that is basically going to take that first weird dash and replace it with a normal dash character for me (along with other replacements of course)

Comment: @DourHighArch The `?` already comes as the result of an implicit conversion - for an unsupported character. You *can't* fit all the characters into Latin1. Even if `―` is converted to `-` (I don't know or care), there will be many characters with no equivalent mapping ..

Comment: @Dudeman3000 Then consider my question suggestion (as a basis for searching, at least): "How to encode Unicode HTML as ASCII?"

Comment: @pst, and `Encoding.Convert` does not try to fit all characters into latin1. It omits them, as I thought Duderman wanted.

Comment: @DourHighArch Does he really want *lost* data? I guess we have different ideas of clean/sanitize .. (edit in response to following comment: "I guess so")

Comment: Encoding.Convert is what I was looking for - thanks Dour!  pst, I will remove the HTML tag and drop it from the title. --- looks like I spoke too soon... yeah, I would rather not drop characters but in this particular case it might be an option.

Comment: You can store text in any encoding in blob fields (`image` in SQL Server terms) - that, of course, means change in the table schema.

Comment: That sounds pretty good Igor... I'll update this post if I make that change - thanks!  At this point I think that maybe the only better solution would be a piece of brute force "replace this character with that character" C# code. Shotgun not writing that piece of code...