# Replace Double Double Quotes in UTF-8 String to single Double quotes

Tags: vb.net

I have string that is formatted in UTF-8.

```
"{""messages"":[{""messageId"":""245043"",""campaignId"":""14085""
```

I need to replace the double double quotes to single double quotes.

The following is able to replace double quotes to double single quotes

```
        NewMessage = Replace(Message, "““", "''")
```

But I can't figure out how to replace the double double quotes to single double quotes.

The code was written in vb.net and the desired output is:

```
"{"messages":[{"messageId":"245043","campaignId":"14085"
```

Added image from watch

[image]

Solution Provided by o_O

[image]

Comment: That looks like JSON - if so, are you sure you want to fiddle with it manually...or that it actually comes that way?

Comment: It's badly formatted Jason

Comment: Can you edit the question and put the desired output

Comment: I have added the desired output

Comment: First replace single [double quotes] with single [single quotes]. Then replace double [single qoutes] to single [double quotes] and then if any [single qoute] is left, replace it with [double qoute]

Comment: It didn't work and I think the reason is the encoding of the string.
I tried both with simple replace and using CHR as well.

Comment: If encoding might be the issue, check similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/c-sharp-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-latin1-h)

Comment: This is a mistake, you are being mislead by the way the debugger displays strings.  It makes an effort to show them the way you'd write them in a program.  Click the spyglass icon to activate the text visualizer, you'll see that the string does not actually contain doubled double quotes.

Comment: You are 100% right

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the [Chr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.chr(v=vs.110).aspx) function for this:

```
NewMessage = Message.Replace(Chr(34) & Chr(34), Chr(34))
```

Comment: You can't use it or it's not working for you?  I just did a test of this and it worked fine.

Comment: Its not working for me. Tried it before making the post

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data is coming from somewhere in 
`"{""messages"":[{""messageId"":""245043"",""campaignId"":""14085""` 
 format, so for the sake of the question I'm formatting the input in a proper way:

```
Dim str As String  =  """{""""messages"""":[{""""messageId"""":""""245043"""",""""campaignId"""":""""14085"""""
Console.WriteLine("Input : " & str)
str = str.Replace("""","'").Replace("''","""").Replace("'","""")
Console.WriteLine("Output : " & str)
```

Output:

```
Input : "{""messages"":[{""messageId"":""245043"",""campaignId"":""14085""

Output : "{"messages":[{"messageId":"245043","campaignId":"14085"
```

Check it on [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rHcBm4)

Comment: Yes! 100%, your solution works when you provide the string.
I will post image of what happens with your solution when applied to my string.