# How to check invalid semicolon not in the keyboard in c#

Tags: c#

I could not able to check the invalid semicolon in the code.
I unsure how the client is posting the invalid character, due to that the system getting error.
I have the invalid semicolon,(;) but I could not able to recreate the invalid semi-column in the editor(code). When trying to paste the invalid semicolon into the editor, it is converting automatically to normal keyboard value(;). So the scope of the invalid semicolon getting ignored in the code
The invalid semicolon is only visible in some of the textboxes like gmail,gira

I have tried with following

```
public string ReplaceInvalidIso8859Characters(string str)
        {
            var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {";", ";"}

            };

            var newBodyBuilder = new StringBuilder(str);
            replacements.ForEach(_ => newBodyBuilder.Replace(_.Key, _.Value));
            return newBodyBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5jGr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bDw4.png)

Comment: [Why images are not good while posting a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/c-sharp-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-latin1-h
Does this help?

Comment: Why is that semicolon considered invalid? What do you use the semicolons for?

Comment: Unicode never disappoints.  Possible candidates are U+037E (likely to appear in Greek text, question mark) and U+FF1B (likely to appear in Japanese text).  Let the debugger tell you which one it is, inspect str.ToCharArray() and switch to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use character codes for this,
you can convert any incompatible characters in the editor to semicolun ("U + 003B") in 
c # 
`char c1 = '\ u003B';`
You can catch the way. For other character codes
Have a look at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003b/encoding.htm