# Encoding issue with spanish file in C#

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I have a file store online in an azure blob storage in spanish. Some word have special charactere (for example : Almacén)
When I open the file in notepad++, the encoding is ANSI.

So now I try to read the file with the code :

```
        using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        blobStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var allLines = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
```

the issue is that "allLines" are not proper encoding, I have some issue like : Almac�n

I have try some solution like this one :
[C# Convert string from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 (Latin1) H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922199/c-sharp-convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1-latin1-h)

but still not working

(the final goal is to "merge" two csv so I read the stream of both, remove the header and concatenate the string to push it again. If there is a better solution to merge csv in c# that can skip this encoding issue I am open to it also)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read a non-UTF8 encoded file as if it was UTF8 encoded. I can replicate this issue with

```
var s = "Almacén";
using var memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(s));

using var reader = new StreamReader(memStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var allLines = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

Console.WriteLine(allLines); // writes "Almac�n" to console
```

You should be attempting to read the file with encoding iso-8859-1 "Western European (ISO)" which is codepage 28591.

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(Stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
var allLines = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
```